# In What Way are Set Theorists' 'Experiences' in the CH Worlds Flawed, if Any?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

This is in regards to Joel David Hamkins' new paper "IS THE DREAM SOLUTION OF THE CONTINUUM HYPOTHESIS ATTAINABLE?" (look under title in arXiv). I quote from the last paragraph of his paper:

"My challenge to anyone who proposes to give a particular, definite answer to CH is that they must not only argue for their particular answer, mustering whatever philosophical or intuitive support for their answer as they can, but also they must explain away the illusion of our experience with the contrary hypothesis.  Only by doing so will they overcome the response I have described, rejection of the argument from extensive evidence of the contrary.  Before we will be able to accept CH as true, we must come to know that our experience of the not-CH worlds was somehow flawed; we must come to see our experience in those lands as illusory."

Let me make a slight variation in the last sentence of his I quoted:

Before we will be able to accept not-CH as true, we must come to know that our experience of the CH worlds was somehow flawed; we must come to see our experience in those lands as illusory.

Since the goal of set theory (at least from Hamkins' perspective of the orthodox view (the set-theoretical universe as unique--it is the universe of all sets, "The set-Theoretical Multiverse: a model-theoretic philosophy of set theory")) is to have V (for ZFC, for example) to contain all possible sets short of inconsistency, it would seem that from this perspective that the CH worlds are already flawed and that to defend CH against not-CH one would have to say that the existence of 'Cohen reals' in the not-CH worlds is somehow illusory (or at least the belief that one can add sufficient number of Cohen reals to make CH false from the Naturalist View of Forcing perspective).  Can one make the view showing that either Cohen reals are illusory, or that the ability to add sufficient number of Cohen reals so as to make not-CH true is illusory, coherent?

Comment: Isn't this rather argumentative?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "argumentative". We all agree that the question cannot be settled the on purely "axiomatic/deductive" playground. The interesting thing, however, is that while AC is commonly (but not universally) accepted because it enables us to prove many useful down to Earth things that would be undecidable otherwise, and rejected by some because it brings up a few clear monsters like Banach-Tarski, the implications of CH or its negation in the "everyday math" are much less transparent. So, the question is "can we get something our intuition revolts against from negating CH?"


Comment: Link to "Is the dream solution to the continuum hypothesis attainable?" by Joel David Hamkins: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4026

Comment: I suggest the math-philosophy tag. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How kind of you to take an interest in my paper. Please see also
[my blog
post about the dream solution](http://jdh.hamkins.org/dream-solution-of-ch/) and the [arxiv entry](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4026) for the paper.

First, I shall make a quibble, and then I'll address your question
at the end.

The quibble is that your quotation from the paper is not accurate.
The full paragraph from the paper reads:

> > I have argued, then, that there will be no dream solution of the continuum hypothesis.
> >     Let me now go somewhat beyond this claim and issue a challenge to
> >     those who propose to solve the continuum problem by some other
> >     means. My challenge to anyone who proposes to give a particular,
> >     definite answer to CH is that they must not only argue for their
> >     preferred answer, mustering whatever philosophical or intuitive
> >     support for their answer as they can, but also they must explain
> >     away the illusion of our experience with the contrary hypothesis.
> >     Only by doing so will they overcome the response I have described,
> >     rejection of the argument from extensive experience of the
> >     contrary. Before we will be able to accept CH as true, we must come
> >     to know that our experience of the $\neg$CH worlds was somehow
> >     flawed; we must come to see our experience in those lands as
> >     illusory. It is insufficient to present a beautiful landscape, a
> >     shining city on a hill, for we are widely traveled and know that it
> >     is not the only one.

The difference is that it should say "extensive experience of the
contrary" rather than "extensive evidence of the contrary", a
difference that affects the meaning, since the point is that we
have experience in both the CH and in the $\neg$CH worlds. In
particular, there is a symmetry here, and I hope it was clear that
implicitly include your variation as part of my intended meaning.

Now, let me consider your final question, which is very good.

- Can one make the view showing that either Cohen reals are illusory,
  or that the ability to add sufficient number of Cohen reals so as to make not-CH true is illusory, coherent?

I take the answer to be yes, these views are made coherent by what
I have called the *universe* view in my paper
[The set-theoretic multiverse](http://jdh.hamkins.org/themultiverse/), from
which the dream solution paper is adapted. The universe view is the
view I am arguing against, and although I have attacked the
universe view for being mistaken, I do not attack it as incoherent.
The question is whether the alternative set-theoretic universes
that we seem to have discovered via forcing and other methods exist
as legitimate concepts of set or not. I have argued at length that
they do. But the opposing universe view is that no, there is just
one absolute background concept of set, and the purpose of set
theory is to discover what is true there. This seems to be a
perfectly *coherent* view. It is a view advanced explicitly by
Daniel Isaacson, who I quote extensively in my dream solution
paper, and also by Donald Martin, in his paper "Multiple universes
of sets and indeterminism in set theory", Topoi 20, 5--16, 2001,
among others.

Criticizing my argument, Peter Koellner has emphasized that one can
view my account of the naturalist account of forcing, rather than
providing evidence that forcing extensions are real, instead as the 
desired explanation of the illusion of forcing extensions of $V$.
And perhaps this criticism is the detailed answer to your question.
That is, Koellner argues that the details of the proof of the
naturalist account of forcing is how one explains away the illusion
of forcing. So that would seem to be a coherent view. My reply to
that argument, in my multiverse paper, is that such an account of
forcing seems fundamentally crippling to our mathematical
intuition, if we must regard all talk of actual forcing extensions
of $V$ as ever-more-fantastical simulations of the extensions
inside $V$, something like the writings of the exotic-travelogue
writer who never actually ventures west of sixth avenue, or the
absurdity of the mathematician who insists that yes, the real
numbers exist with a full Platonic existence, but the complex
numbers do not; they must be simulated inside the reals, such as
with ordered pairs. The multiverse perspective makes a
philosophically simple position, taking the existence of the
forcing extensions at face value, while nurturing a robust use of
forcing that will ultimately aid our set-theoretical understanding.

Finally, let me say that I agree completely with Andrej's point
about geometry, and I discuss this analogy in section 4 of my
multiverse paper.

Comment: Let me also apologize to those who object to having mathematical philosophy on MO, who I hope will allow it. The truth is that much of the current work in the philosophy of set theory involves deeply philosophical issues surrounding some of the most technical methods and ideas, such as forcing and large cardinals, and the subject requires experts in both realms, mathematics and philosophy, to progress. 

Comment: Some of us actually wish there were lots more mathematical philosophy (at a proper 'research' level) on MO!

Comment: @ Prof. Hamkins:

Sorry to have misquoted you.  I would still be interested in getting a sense of the experience set theorists' have in the CH and GCH worlds.
Is there a survey article which covers that experience?  If so, please let me know.  Also, have you any idea how the notion of set theory being the foundations of mathematics will survive in the set-theoretic multiverse?  Should it?

Comment: No problem---don't worry about it. As for getting experience in the CH, GCH and $\neg$CH worlds, I would recommend any of the standard treatments of forcing and iterated forcing. My sense of the future for viewing set theory as a foundation of mathematics is that this will continue as it has, in that set theorists will continue to explore the diversity of models of set theory, while quietly abandoning the sometimes-heard remarks concerning what is "really" true.

Comment: Has the referenced blog post been deleted?   The link leads to a page showing the title, but no further content.

Comment: Sorry, my blog is having problems, and I'm trying to fix it when I have time. The paper is available at https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/review-of-symbolic-logic/article/settheoretic-multiverse/B27885BC5F1D9860585F070B5DE1D53A. Also on the arxiv at https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223.

Answer (score 33):

I find it useful to make an analogy between what set theorists and geometers do.

A geometer has mastered the study of models of a certain theory known as "affine geometry". He eats models of geometry for breakfast, he can *imagine* them, and has developed an *intuition* about them. Questions about Euclid's fifth postulate were historically important for the development of geometry, but nowadays we understand the situation very well. We have outgrown questions such as "is the fifth postulate *really* true" and "are non-euclidean geometries just an illusion?".

A set theorist has mastered the study of models of a certain theory knowns as "ZFC". He eats models of sets for breakfast, he can *imagine* them, and has developed an *intuition* about them. Questions about Cantor's Hypothesis were historically important for the development of set theory, but nowadays we understand the situation very well. Why then have we *not* outgrown questions such as "is CH *really* true" and "are models of not-CH just an illusion?"

Whatever the reasons, the best thing a set theorist can do is write a paper in which he explains as carefully as he can to the semi-, pseudo- and quasi-experts that in fact there is a wealth of models of ZFC, just like there is a wealth of geometries. The models of ZFC are *not* superior or inferior according to whether they validate Cantor's hypthesis, just like the geometries are *not* superior or inferior according to whether they validate the fifth postulate.

Comment: Very nice analogy.

Comment: I have questions regarding the analogy between set theory and geometry,
primarily the following:

We know that in some cases we can represent alternatives to Euclid's fifth postulate as holding in spaces having curvature.  The notion of curvature in spaces provides a larger context in which it makes sense
to speak of the equality of alternative geometries.  What is the larger context, if any, that allows one to speak of the equality of models of set theory coherently? This isn't to say that set theorists can't explore every possible model of set theory-- 

Comment: what is the larger context that makes the set-theoretic multiverse a coherent whole?  Has one been discovered yet?

Comment: Also, what happens to set theory as the foundation of mathematics under the multiverse view?  Is essentially the 'foundationalist' program dead and buried?  

Comment: For Andrej Bauer:

When you state "Questions about Cantor's Hypothesis were historically important for the development of set theory, but nowadays we understand the situation very well.", what is this "situation" set theorists understand very well.  What are the intuitions set theorists have developed regarding the models of ZFC where CH and GCH hold? I accept your answer as being the orthodox(?) view of set theorists, who of course have every right to study any and all models of ZFC.  

Comment: But the geometries are superior according to whether or not they validate the fifth postulate, since our universe is known to be non-Euclidean.

Comment: First of all, this is an *analogy*, not a mathematical theorem, so we can't expect to drive the analogy too far.

Comment: @Hwitz: I wonder what you would have said in the 16th century version of Mathoverflow.

Comment: @Benjamin: if set-theorists have a strong intuition about the set-theoretic multiverse, but they are at the present unable to describe it with rigorous mathematical methods, then we should all rejoice to have something new and grand to work on. And of course, since there is a multiverse, the idea that mathematics is founded upon one tiny little undetermined point of the universe becomes silly. The new view of foundations will simply have to be more relativistic in nature.

Comment: Thomas, regarding your comment above to Andrej ("I accept your answer as being the orthodox view of set theorists"), I don't think that is quite right. Although I share Andrej's perspective, this is not the orthodox position in set theory, which is rather the position that I have called the universe view, the view that there is an absolute set-theoretic background concept of set, with a determinate answer to CH. Indeed, it was the criticism of this orthodox view that I took as my task in these papers mentioned here.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that I am *not* a set theorist and I do *not* eat models of classical set theory for breakfast, but I know precisely what Joel is getting at because I *do* eat models of intuitionistic mathematics for breakfast. That's a larger multiverse than Joel's.

Comment: @Prof. Hamkins:
Sorry to have misquoted you.  Still and all, it would be nice to have a synopsis of set theorist's experience in CH and GCH worlds.  Is there a survey article you know of that provides such a synopsis?  For my part, I side with the not-CH advocates because I myself believe that there is no reason to believe that Cohen (or for that matter Random) reals are not 'real' and because I believe that the universal quantifier in the Power Set Axiom should be interpreted as 'all possible subsets'.  I hope to find the philosophical flaws in my own position.  Hope you can help.  

Comment: Thomas, with such a view, then you should also accept all generic reals for collapsing sets to $\omega$, and so you should likely think that every set is countable. So you are working in some theory like ZFC-, without power set+every set is countable. But even that isn't quite right, since one can always add more generic reals, and so your concept should be something like an ever-growing incompleted totality. It is something like the union of the multiverse, but it isn't clear to me even that we should expect separation and replacement to hold. The theory might not be nice.

Comment: My conception is (for better or worse) the following:

1.  Begin by forming L
2.  Use forcing to extend |P(omega)| to Aleph-2 without collapsing cardinals forming a new 'universe' V
3.  Use forcing without collapsing cardinals to extend |P(omega)| to  
Aleph-3 and continuing using forcing in this manner to form a chain of
forcing extensions of L for all cardinals using this theorem of Cohen
as a rule, "In N (the forcing extension of L which add reals but does not collapse cardinals) C= Aleph-alpha if alpha is not cofinal with omega in M (L, or the universe previously constructed by forcing)

Comment: C=Aleph-(alpha+1) if alpha is cofinal with omega" (Cohen, SET THEORY AND THE CONTINUUM HYPOTHESIS. pg 134, Thm 4), then take the 'Universe of Interest' to be the union of L and the forcing extensions over all Alephs.  The essential idea here is that the real line should consist of all possible (Cohen) reals (short of inconsistency).  I'm sure there are problems with my formulation so I would appreciate any help removing the bugs. Thanks in advance for any help given along those lines.  

Comment: Thomas, that amounts to class forcing with $\text{Add}(\omega,\text{Ord})$, as we discussed in the answer to another question of yours. But why stop there? This is not *all* Cohen reals over $L$, since one can add still more. Indeed, we can seem to add a Cohen real over any model you present. And if one really wants *all* Cohen reals, then there is little reason to suppose that they can be amalgamated into one model, as we mention in our geology paper: for any countable model $M\models$ZFC, there are $M$-generic Cohen reals $c,d$, such that $M[c]$ and $M[d]$ have no common extension.

Comment: Prof. Hamkins, Is there then a property of Cohen reals that ensures that the forcing extensions containing them form a chain (I, of course want the Cohen reals I am speaking of to form a very large complete linear order--a 'real line').   

Comment: @Prof Hamkins:  I was rereading your Set Theoretic Geology paper and had a question regarding Observation 31 (the Theorem you quote in your last comment to me) and its proof:  Do both carry over to a naturalist account of forcing?  If so, what would be the class- model analogue to the statement, "From this map, we may reconstruct z in U, which reveals all the ordinals of W to be countable, a contradiction if U and W have the same ordinals."  Would the Countability Principle be used to implement the translation?          

Comment: Also a question regarding Theorem 32 in "Set-Theoretic Geology":  given that Theorem 32 and its proof can translate to a naturalist account of forcing, are you essentially saying that the union of all the W[G(i)] in Theorem 32 would not form a model of ZFC ( in other words, you cannot use forcing to create an analogue of the Cumulative Hierarchy which 'fattens' V)?

Comment: One more question:  Are you familiar with Dana Scott's paper "Axiomatizing Set Theory" (found in PROCEEDINGS OF SYMPOSIA IN PURE MATHEMATICS, Vol 13, Part II, 1974)?  I mention this because the system of axioms discussed therein might be useful in formulating the Naturalist Account of Forcing.    

Answer (score 11):

I would like to add to the thoughtful answers to this question and also respond to a couple points made in the answers.  Please note that this is mostly a philosophical answer.

The part of the question that I would like to address is

> . . . it would seem that from this perspective that the CH worlds are already flawed and that to defend CH against not-CH one would have to say that the existence of 'Cohen reals' in the not-CH worlds is somehow illusory

It might seem like since there are a variety of universes, that some of them must be flawed. In particular that since there are universes which are models of $CH$ and $\neg CH$ that some of these universes must be flawed. The accepted answer to this question has shown that it is coherent to resolve this difficulty in thinking by calling conflicting universes or sets illusions.  However, one can overcome this apparent cognitive difficulty by living locally in the multiverse.  For the purpose of understanding how to see through the proper perspective in the set-theoretic multiverse, let me create some characters, if you will tolerate, which live in the multiverse. Suppose in the multiverse there are travelers and inhabitants. Travelers like to travel far and wide and often, while inhabitants like to stay home.  Let's go to a universe $V$ which models $GCH$.  Inhabitants in this universe know that the continuum hypothesis is true.  However, they also know that there are many travelers coming to visit their universe.  An inhabitant meets a traveler who has just arrived from another universe $W$ where the continuum is $\aleph_{10}$.  The traveler sees that in universe $V$ the continuum is $\aleph_1$, and so accepts that the continuum is now a different size because she is in a new place.  The inhabitant is having a more difficult time understanding since he has not traveled beyond his native universe.  The traveler tells him that in universe $W$ the size of the real numbers is $\aleph_{10}$, but he doesn't understand because the size of the real numbers is most definitely $\aleph_1$, and he has no "experience of the contrary".  So, the traveler decides to take him with her to another universe $X$ where the continuum is $\aleph_2$.  Via a generic filter and forcing relation, they travel to universe $X$ where the inhabitant of universe $V$ can now see with his own eyes that in this world the continuum is indeed the second uncountable cardinal!  So, truth in the multiverse depends on location.  This way of understanding is discussed in detail in Hamkins' paper on the set-theoretic multiverse, and in the paper regarding a dream solution to CH which is quoted below:

> Part of my goal in the multiverse article was to tease apart two often-blurred aspects of set-theoretic Platonism, namely, to separate the claim that the set-theoretic universe has a real mathematical existence from the claim that it is unique.

Second, I would like to respond to Andrej's perspective that all universes are created equal.  I think that there are places in the multiverse which are more pleasant than others depending on one's preferences.  For example, the inhabitants of a universe where $GCH$ holds might believe that their universe is the best since there are so many travelers who have a lay-over there.  I like this type of universe very much and indeed in my experience with forcing, it is very helpful (in order to count in the ground model) to have the $GCH$ hold. I have also been to a universe where Martin's Axiom holds and I really liked doing mathematics in that universe.  However, some regions of the multiverse may be less appealing, say a universe without the axiom of choice.

Finally, I would like to address the second to last paragraph of Joel's response.  He says that it is crippling to have to consider the rich set-theoretic multiverse as a mere simulation, an illusion we experience in the universe.  I agree, but I think it is important to discuss and distiguish the difference between the dreams of the universe and the reality of the multiverse.  In every universe, there are the classes of names of other universes with a variety of sizes of the continuum, for example.  But these classes of names are not themselves the universes to which they point since if they were then the universe which dreams of them would not be coherent.  It is only in the presensce of a generic filter that this dream class can become a real universe.  What I am saying is that even if someone holds the view that the multiverse is really an illusion experienced in the universe then that person could not be talking about the actual multiverse, but only a reflection.

Comment: Very nice story, especially, "Via a generic filter and forcing relation, they travel to universe $X$ where the inhabitant of universe $V$ can now see with his own eyes that in this world the continuum is indeed the second uncountable cardinal!" Do I smell a sci-fi novel brewing?

Comment: @Erin:  I have a question regarding the following:  "In every universe, there are classes of names of other universes [forcing extensions?] with a variety of sizes of the continuum, for example.  But these classes of names are not themselves the universes to which they point since if they were then the universe which dreams of them would not be coherent [I presume because then one would end up with an inconsistent theory].  It is only in the presence of a generic filter
[a consistent set of sets?] that this dream class can be can become a real universe."

Comment: Here is my question:  Consider, for example, the formal language of the integers which contains following rule for constructing 'names', 
(a)^(1/n) where a and n are integers and n is not equal to 0.  With this rule one can come up with the following names (-1)^(1/2), (2)^(1/2).  Obviously (-1)^(1/2) names nothing in the reals and (2)^(1/2) names nothing in the rationals although according to the rule
(a)^(1/n) where a, n are integers and n not= 0 these are perfectly well-formed names.  Is this the sense in which you are speaking about


Comment: "In every universe, there are classes of names of other universes"?  Now consider the formal language for L, the constructable universe. Are you, in analogy with my aforementioned simple examples (if I am not stretching this analogy too far, of course) saying that the formal language of L contains the names of all possible Cohen reals, random reals, reals that collapse cardinals, essentially all possible forcing extensions of L?  If so, assuming that the formal language of L is the exact syntactic replica of the universe L then what are these names without referents in L?  Gaps 

Comment: (as per the formal definition of gap in the theory of linear orders)?
Since it seems incoherent to say that reals that collapse cardinals and reals that don't collapse cardinals exist on a single 'real line',
it would seem reasonable to say that each type of real in this case exists on a separate 'branch' of a tree that represents a partial order.  If that is so then the set of names in the formal language of L
would seem to represent the maximal power set (the set of all possible sets definable in the formal language of L).  Is this what you are trying to say, or have I misunderstood?


Comment: @Thomas, I was talking about the class of names in the universe defined recursively which includes check names for all the sets in the ground model and names for all the sets which will be included in a generic extension, for a given boolean algebra (or a partial order which embeds into it) and generic filter.  I don't completely understand your comments, I am just referring to the process of forcing which is standard in the literature, say Kunen or Jech.  I like your question.  If you haven't already, you should read the original ideas in Hamkins' multiverse paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.42

Comment: @Quinn.  Thank you.  I'm glad you liked the story.

Comment: @Erin, what I am trying to ask is simply this, given a model M and its forcing extension M[G], since the names for the generic sets (if I understand correctly) in M[G] are already in M, but the referents of of those names aren't (otherwise M=M[G]), are the names of the generic sets anything like the name (-1)^(1/2) in the language of the integers?  For example, we know that (-1)^(1/2) has no referent in the integers (or even in the reals) but the name can be formed in the language of the integers (since (4)^(1/2) has two referents in the integers, namely 2 and -2).  To take an example    

Comment: in the reals, say for example we express reals in the language of Dedekind cuts over the rationals, i.e. the name of a real is its Dedekind cut over the rationals.  What you seem to be saying is that
relative to the model M and its forcing extension M[G] that the 'name'
(the Dedekind cut) of the Cohen real in M[G] is in M, but the 'point'
(the referent the Dedekind cut in question refers to) is not--in M it is a 'gap' or to the inhabitants of M, a 'well-formed but meaningless 
concatenation of symbols', just like (-1)^(1/2) would be to the inhabitants of the world of the integers 

Comment: (better, think of the set S={a| a=(n/0), where n is an integer}--is there an extension of the reals which contains S ( if I remember correctly, there is a mathematical trick where one allegedly proves '1=2' by implicitly dividing by zero)?  Perhaps if there is such an extension (that the trick exists suggests that there 'is'(?)). Such an extension might be said to 'collapse' the integers....).  Are the names for the generic elements (of whatever type) of M[G] in M loke this?   